# Отображение html

Tags: html

Реализую веб-приложение, однако с отображением html на сервере испытываю некоторые проблемы.
Так выглядит предпросмотр файла index.html.
[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="font-size: 16px;">
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="keywords" content="Port Scanner">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <title>Port Scanner</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="nicepage.css" media="screen">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Главная.css" media="screen">
    <script class="u-script" type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js" defer=""></script>
    <script class="u-script" type="text/javascript" src="nicepage.js" defer=""></script>
    <meta name="generator" content="Nicepage 4.12.5, nicepage.com">
    <link id="u-theme-google-font" rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,100i,300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,700,700i,900,900i|Open+Sans:300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i">
    <link id="u-page-google-font" rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abril+Fatface:400|Architects+Daughter:400">
    
    
    
    <script type="application/ld+json">{
        "@context": "http://schema.org",
        "@type": "Organization",
        "name": ""
}</script>
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#478ac9">
    <meta property="og:title" content="Главная">
    <meta property="og:type" content="website">
  </head>
  <body data-home-page="index.html" data-home-page-title="Главная" class="u-body u-xl-mode">
    <section class="u-black u-clearfix u-section-1" id="sec-5016">
      <div class="u-clearfix u-sheet u-sheet-1">
        <h1 class="u-align-center u-custom-font u-text u-text-1">Port Scanner<br>
        </h1>
        <p class="u-align-center u-custom-font u-text u-text-2">IP adress</p>
        <div class="u-shape u-shape-rectangle u-white u-shape-1"></div>
        <p class="u-align-center u-custom-font u-text u-text-3">Range of ports</p>
        <div class="u-shape u-shape-rectangle u-white u-shape-2"></div>
        <p class="u-align-center u-custom-font u-text u-text-body-color u-text-4">SCAN</p>
        <a href="https://nicepage.com/joomla-page-builder" class="u-border-2 u-border-white u-btn u-btn-round u-button-style u-radius-50 u-white u-btn-1">SCAN</a>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section class="u-clearfix u-section-2" id="sec-c87d">
      <div class="u-clearfix u-sheet u-sheet-1"></div>
    </section>
    
    
    
    <section class="u-backlink u-clearfix u-grey-80">
      <a class="u-link" href="https://nicepage.com/website-templates" target="_blank">
        <span>Website Templates</span>
      </a>
      <p class="u-text">
        <span>created with</span>
      </p>
      <a class="u-link" href="" target="_blank">
        <span>Website Builder Software</span>
      </a>. 
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

Однако когда захожу на сервер, то появляется вот это:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
**upd**
Консоль:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**upd2**
Структура приложения
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Смущает href="Главная.css"
Возможно, в запросе идет %D0%93%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F.css

Comment: css верно подключен?

Comment: как это можно проверить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

замените Главная.css на index.css или на другое иное название.

[image: ошибка]

Вы можете посмотреть подключен ли css к html через консоль там будет ошибка если не удалось подключить или через elements в dom дереве посмотреть

Подключить css можно так

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
```

Comment: выскакивают ошибки(upd)

Comment: Скриншот в вопросе(заголовок upd)

Comment: 404 ошибка , css не найден

Comment: как его подключить?

Comment: Можете показать структуру приложение? где находится index.html и сам css

Comment: в upd2 выложил.

Comment: не нужно файлы называть по русский! Переменуй всё на англ. index.html, index.css и тд